# OnClick insertText or Clean

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a input, and My Java-script function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function insertText(elemID, text)
        {
            var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
            elem.innerHTML += text;
        }
    </script>
        <textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Insert some text" onclick="insertText('txt1', '<?php echo getTheBest50('','') ?>');">
```

With this function, **`onClick`** I show text on input from my function. I would like if i click second time to clean the input. Right now every time i click it adds my text again.

Thanks

Comment: means when you click second time text box should be clear?

Comment: what is `getTheBest50()` here, please explain clearly

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya yes

Comment: @Ms.Nehal just my function that returns the text

Answer (score 2):

```
function insertText(elemID, text)
{
  // Get value from an input
  var input_val  = document.getElementById('elemID').value;
 // set Input empty  
    document.getElementById('elemID').value = '';
// to set value
   document.getElementById('elemID').value = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function insertText(elemID, text) {
    var getValue = $("#"+elemID).val()=="" ? text : "";
    $("#"+elemID).val(getValue);
}
```

use the jquery library and use the above code to make it simple..

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pure javascript (not jQuery) function, use this:

```js
function insertText(elemID, text) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
  if( elem.innerHTML == '' ) {
    elem.innerHTML += text;
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt1"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Insert some text" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'Demo text');">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function insertText(elemID, text)
{
 var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
 if(elem.innerHTML=="")
  {
     elem.innerHTML = text;
  }else{
     elem.innerHTML="";
  }
}
```

Comment: The onclick function contains a second parameter (text). So it won't be empty.